# Virtualbox connection disappears

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I've tried to reinstall my virtualbox (because all of a sudden I didn't have connections adapters which were there by default) and it spawns these two connections for Virtualbox (as it should) but they disappear seconds after the installation. Why is this happening and how could I fix this? It could be related to recent Windows 10 update, as I'm sure it worked before that and didn't work after that. However there might be other factors as well.

To give you specifics, in my "Network Connections" folder I now have 3 (Ethernet, Wi-Fi, Virtualbox Host-Only network) while I should have 4 (Ethernet, Wi-Fi, 2 related to Virtualbox).

P.s. Everything worked fine for a year until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but Google took me here, so others may land here too ;-)
As a refresh to the question asked here, after upgrades to :

- Windows 10 build 1909
- VirtualBox 6.1.22 (previously using version 6.1.18 which ran fine)

I also started experimenting the "Host-only network" interfaces being there and suddenly disappearing.

**Things that did NOT work for me :**

1. Reinstalling VirtualBox version 6.1.22
2. Downgrading to version 6.1.18

**Solution :** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10/33733454#33733454))

1. Open Windows Network Connections
2. Right click the "Host only adapter" created by VirtualBox
3. Choose properties
4. Check "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver" (if already checked : uncheck + recheck it)
5. Disable and enable the adapter

Answer (score 0):

try to install or update latest virtual box and after install 
VirtualBox 5.1.6 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: I did. With the recent Virtualbox update I noticed the disappearance. It was 4 connections for a mere second before it disappeared. I will try the extension pack now.

Comment: Nothing. Here's the error it throws:

Interface ('VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2') is not a Host-Only Adapter interface (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).